# Cabal: Does not exists in Windows 8.1

Tags: haskell, cabal

Today I installed windows 8.1 and haskell on my laptop. I'm trying to build my own haskell library, but I got an error when I try to use cabal sdist. This is the error:

```
D:\Development\School\AFP\Assignments\Practice\Exercise\Project>cabal sdist
Distribution quality errors:
'license: NONE' is not a recognised license. The known licenses are: GPL,
GPL-2, GPL-3, LGPL, LGPL-2.1, LGPL-3, AGPL, AGPL-3, BSD2, BSD3, MIT, ISC,
MPL-2.0, Apache, Apache-2.0, PublicDomain, AllRightsReserved, OtherLicense
Distribution quality warnings:
No 'category' field.
No 'maintainer' field.
No 'synopsis' field.
A 'license-file' is not specified.
When distributing packages it is encouraged to specify source control
information in the .cabal file using one or more 'source-repository' sections.
See the Cabal user guide for details.
Note: the public hackage server would reject this package.
Warning: Cannot run preprocessors. Run 'configure' command first.
Building source dist for Project-0.1.0.0...
cabal: does not exist
```

Before I used the "cabal sdist" I used the following commands:

1. cabal init
2. cabal sandbox init
3. cabal install -j

Every command succeed, except for the cabal sdist. The cabal install only gives the following warning:

```
D:\Development\School\AFP\Assignments\Practice\Exercise\Project>cabal install -j

Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following will be installed:
Project-0.1.0.0 (reinstall)
Warning: Note that reinstalls are always dangerous. Continuing anyway...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at
D:\Development\School\AFP\Assignments\Practice\Exercise\Project\.cabal-sandbox
Configuring Project-0.1.0.0...
Building Project-0.1.0.0...
Installed Project-0.1.0.0
```

This is my Project.cabal file:

```
-- Initial Project.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further 
-- documentation, see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

-- Initial Project.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further 
-- documentation, see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                Project
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:            
description:         Education
license:             NONE
-- license-file:     
-- author:              
-- maintainer:          
-- copyright:           
-- category:            
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files: File6, File5, File4, File3, File2 
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  exposed-modules:     File1
  -- other-modules:       
  -- other-extensions:    
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && <4.9, QuickCheck >=2.8 && <2.9
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

I tried google, but I can't find a good solution. I use the following versions:

Cabal version: 1.22.4.0

Haskell version: 7.10.2

If you need more information, please ask.

Comment: This may help you: http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2015/06/cabals-does-not-exist-error-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that cabal could not find the files in extra-source-files. I thought I didn't had to add the extension of the haskell files, but this is required.

I also had another problem. The extra-source-files wasn't using the hs-source-dirs, so I had to explicitly write "src/" infront of a file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about `sdist`, but the problem is clear: you've specified 'NONE' as the license in your cabal file, but that is not allowed for the `sdist` option. `configure`, `build`, and `init` don't care about the specific license, but `sdist` apparently does.

For more info, I searched google for "cabal sdist" and found [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program).

> This [`cabal sdist`] has the advantage that Cabal will do a bit more checking, and ensure that the tarball has the structure that HackageDB expects.

HackageDB probably expects a valid license, hence why "NONE" is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this was not the problem. Cabal sdist will create a tar if there is no license file.